# Is there a closed form expression for $\int_0^{2\pi}Q(a+\cos x)dx?$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Let $Q(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_x^{\infty}e^{-u^2/2}du (x\in \mathbb{R})$, where $Q$ is the [$Q$-function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q-function). I want to evaluate the following integral: $$I(a)=\int_0^{2\pi}Q(a+\cos x)dx,\ a\in \mathbb{R}.$$  Does $I(a)$ have a closed form expression? For $a=0$, the integral becomes really simple and can be evaluated to be $\pi$, which follows from the periodicity of $\cos$ as well as the property $Q(x)+Q(-x)=1$. However, I am not sure how to proceed for $a\ne 0$. Can someone help? Thanks in advance.

**Edit:** An interesting observation: We can express $I(a)$ in the following alternate form, $$I(a)=\int_0^\infty \int_0^{2\pi}e^{-r^2/2}Q(a+\cos x)rdrdx=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-(x^2+y^2)/2}Q\left(a+\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\right)dx dy$$

Comment: Did you end up with an expression that contains the integral $$\int_0^{\pi/2}\int_{-a-\cos(x)}^{a-\cos(x)}e^{-u^2/2}\,du\,dx?$$If so, have you tried interchanging the order of integration?

Comment: Yes,I obtained $$\int_0^{\pi/2}\int_{a+\cos x}^{-a+\cos x}e^{-u^2/2}du dx.$$

Comment: Interchanging the order of integration seems to be a good approach. Thanks @MarkViola.

Comment: Does the interchange lead to anything tractable?

Comment: The interchange seems to be not much better than what can be obtained by using integration by parts and taking $Q(\cos x +a)$ to be the first function.

Comment: Specifically, using integration by parts I obtained the following: $$\int_0^\pi Q(a+\cos x)dx=\pi Q(a-1)-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_0^\pi x\sin x e^{-(\cos x +a)^2}dx.$$ Can this be further simplified?